# Ubuntu installation does not detect internal hdd with Windows 10 preinstalled

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, uefi

So, i have bought a new hp laptop with Windows 10 preinstalled. I have been trying to install Ubuntu and Kali linux on it but there are problems:
Kali Linux : The usb drive is not detected at all right from bios.
Ubuntu: I am able to boot into live mode. But when I try to install it, it does not detect the internal hard drive. Gparted also does not detect the hdd. I have tried using the most common steps - 1) disable fastboot 2) sata controller to AHCI 2) disable secure boot. Didn't work. I also disabled TPM thinking it might be causing some problem. Doing a fresh install of windows is out of question. I am attaching some screen captures to make it easier to find a solution to this problem.[[image][[image: ][1]2]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `sudo parted --list` detect anything?  I see your windows filesystem is encrypted with bitlocker. Maybe this is the cause.

Comment: only the live usb drive is visible